# Get countries that have a region selector in checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout

I need to somehow obtain a list of countries that have a region selector (not input box) in the checkout. I know Canada is one of them. There is a bug in one of the modules I use which needs to be fixed by this.

I have no idea how i would go around to even google this.

Any idea how i would achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento saves regions for the countries for which it shows the selector in the **`directory_country_region`** table.

So, you can easily run the following query to get the list of countries which show region selector:

```
SELECT DISTINCT country_id FROM directory_country_region
```